# Why does this give me an error?

Tags: javascript

```
var nop = {}; 
var f = {}; 
[nop.foo] = (f.foo || undefined);
```

Note `f.foo` is not present.

Returns the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `nop.foo = ` would work, but `[]` is an array reference, for which you have no array specified. and `nop.foo` doesn't exist, so it can't be used as a key for this nameless array.

Comment: Are you trying to do destructuring with an object property that doesn't exist ?

Comment: It has to be defined as `[a, b] = [1, 2];` etc. where the given values are in brackets as well.

Comment: I believe it's trying to iterate over `undefined` to match up the indices of the array. Since `undefined` is not iterable, it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the reason is your destructuring `[nope.foo]` is not matching to `(whatEver)` so you'd better change it so:

```js
var nop = {};
var f = {};
[nop.foo] = [(f.foo || 23)];
console.log(nop)
```